# Is it possible to use the same PuppetDB from different Puppet Master versions?

Tags: puppet

I am in the middle of migrating a complex Puppet 5 managed infrastructure to Puppet 7. As this is not possible in one rush, we prepared a new Puppet 7 master and tested code. The caveat is that due to exported resources there is a bootstrapping issue as the PuppetDB in Puppet 7 is still empty and would lead to massive data purges on the nodes.

Now the question that I could not yet answer is: Is it possible and advisable to use the same PuppetDB for different Puppet masters with different versions. So in an ideal world I'd let Puppet 5 and Puppet 7 report to the same PuppetDB which should prevent data purges based on yet missing Puppet 7 runs on existing nodes.

If this is possible, is it advisable to use a central PuppetDB version 5 or version 7?

Best.

p.s.: My alternative approach is bumping ttl on PuppetDB 5, importing and migrating the data in PuppetDB 7, but that might miss newer changes.

Comment: Are you proposing that you might have one Puppetdb instance serving both a Puppet 5 master and a Puppet 7 master at the same time?  I'm pretty sure that an instance can serve multiple masters for the same site at the same time, but Puppetdb is versioned together with the Puppet platform overall, so I am pretty apprehensive about major-version mismatch between server and DB.